# VLOOKUP inside an ARRAY to search another Google Sheets book

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a document 'A' where I have a formula in a 'SEARCH' tab to search for a value from another 'ENTRIES' tab in Google Sheets based on a cell reference written by the user in the same 'SEARCH' tab than the formula.

If I duplicate the 'SEARCH' tab in another Google sheets document/book 'B', how should the formula be altered so that it still references 'A'?

The original formula is based on: 
[Search a value from another tab/sheet in google sheets based on cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331808/search-a-value-from-another-tab-sheet-in-google-sheets-based-on-cell-reference)

**WORKING EXAMPLE HERE** (This would be document 'B' and it tries to reference a search in another document 'A'): **https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ffl6IbehI0slLChyuW-MDezF2xwt0rX12JNIaCFvEI8/edit?usp=sharing**   (*You can see in cell B8 the formula with `IMPORTRANGE` that I'm trying to implement*)

And this would be document'A'. Originally it is an example of how to search for values in another tab based in a different cell reference : 
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit?usp=sharing]

I also checked:

- [Google Sheets VLOOKUP of multiple columns across multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874523/google-sheets-vlookup-of-multiple-columns-across-multiple-sheets)
- [VLOOKUP to the left from another sheet in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064287/vlookup-to-the-left-from-another-sheet-in-google-sheets?rq=1)
- Docs Editors help: IMPORTRANGE https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340

My original formula in book 'A' is:

```
    =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(B3<>"",SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(B3, {data!AN:AN, data!A:BN},  {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ),
    IF(C3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(C3, {data!AK:AK, data!A:BN}, {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), 
    IF(E3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(E3, {data!BJ:BJ, data!A:BN}, {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), 
    IF(D3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
        VLOOKUP(D3, {data!R:R, data!A:BN}, {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), 
    CHAR(10))), "♦", ), ))))), "no match found")
```

I was trying to use : `VLOOKUP(search_key, importrange, index, [is_sorted])` to get in an  `IMPORTRANGE`, like:

```
IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(B3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(B3, {(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit#gid=468700626","data!AN:AN"),
                        (IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit#gid=468700626","data!A:BN")},
                        {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ),
 IF(C3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(C3, {(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit#gid=468700626","data!AK:AK"),
                        (IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit#gid=468700626","data!A:BN")},
                        {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), 
 IF(E3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(E3, {(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit#gid=468700626","data!BJ:BJ"),
                        (IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit#gid=468700626","data!A:BN")},
                        {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), 
 IF(D3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(D3, {(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit#gid=468700626","data!R:R"),
                        (IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8/edit#gid=468700626","data!A:BN")},
                        {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), ))))), "no match found")))))))))
```

It marks as ERROR, but even if I change it to be `... VLOOKUP(B3{(IMPORTRANGE("URL","data!R:R"),(IMPORTRANGE("URL","data!A:BN")}, ...` that gets into () both references, it still marks ERROR.

Comment: did you allow access between sheets from importrange before you run it the arrayformula?

Comment: Yes. Access is set to 'anyone with the link' and just to be sure I added a range in a new tab just to check that it indeed imported the data. I think the problem is somewhere  in the formula on where/how I'm adding the import range.

Comment: the next thing that comes to my mind is a bit unusual URL you are using try simply: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiiGX.png

Comment: The URL Im using is one that google gives you when sharing a link.  I still get ERROR. VG:

`=ARRAYFORMULA( IF(B3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(B3, {(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ALPHANUMTEXT/edit#gid=135622###","pivot_r!AN:AN"),                        (IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ALPHANUMTEXT/edit#gid=1356222###","pivot_r!A:BN")}, 
                        {24,3,21,23,14,5,6,9,10,67,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,30,61,27,62,63,64,65,41,38,36,37,31,32,33,34,45}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), ...`

Comment: Ready. Added a link to an example in the Question and edited the code to match it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pharse Error is caused by extra parenthesis which breaks the formula. FX should be:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(B3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(B3, {IMPORTRANGE("1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8","data!AN:AN"),
                         IMPORTRANGE("1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8","data!A:BN")},
                        {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ),
 IF(C3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(C3, {IMPORTRANGE("1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8","data!AK:AK"),
                         IMPORTRANGE("1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8","data!A:BN")},
                        {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), 
 IF(E3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(E3, {IMPORTRANGE("1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8","data!BJ:BJ"),
                         IMPORTRANGE("1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8","data!A:BN")},
                        {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), 
 IF(D3<>"", SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&"♦"&CHAR(10)&"♦", 1, 
            VLOOKUP(D3, {IMPORTRANGE("1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8","data!R:R"),
                         IMPORTRANGE("1qLcJdCn4EdV7lPOAfZ_CMak1LBkve45FL5SXyqBV3L8","data!A:BN")},
                        {41,38,19,11,55,56}, 0)), CHAR(10))), "♦", ), ))))), "no match found")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I added the working example on the question. Also and to sum for anyone who may require an explanation. `IMPORTRANGE` does NOT need the full URL that google gives you for sharing the link. ; just the part between the /d/ and the /edit#gid .  Also there was an extra `( ` right before `IMPORTRANGE` that shouldn't have been there.